# How to merge Alpha mask and RGB image

Tags: java, python, image, alpha

I have two Images.
One an RGB file and another is an Alpha Channel file.

```
from PIL import Image
 
name = 'char_101_sora_2'
 
image = name+'.png'
mask = name+'[alpha].png'
 
img = Image.open(image)
mas = Image.open(mask)
 
pixdata_img = img.load()
pixdata_mas = mas.load()
 
for y in range(mas.size[1]):
    for x in range(mas.size[0]):
        pixdata_img[x, y] = (pixdata_img[x, y][0], pixdata_img[x, y][1], pixdata_img[x, y][2], pixdata_mas[x, y][2])
```

This code is Python to do this.
But I can't understand it, could anyone can explain it or rewrite it to Java?

Comment: @HaraldK In fact, I can do it. This question ends now. It's also what I do for a living but I can offer it for free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        for (int h = 0; h < image.getHeight(); h++) {
            for (int w = 0; w < image.getWidth(); w++) {
                skadi.setRGB(w, h,
                        (((alpha.getRGB(w, h)) & 0xFF) << 24) |
                                (((image.getRGB(w, h) >> 16) & 0xFF) << 16) |
                                ((((image.getRGB(w, h) >> 8) & 0xFF) << 8) |
                                        (image.getRGB(w, h) & 0xFF)));
            }
        }
```

Here is a simple solution to this question.
Also at here: [Merge Alpha Mask and RGB Image with Java](https://gist.github.com/Aloento/8fc78e5428fa268f72e8885ac3662302)

Comment: It can probably be made faster by using `image.getRGB(w, h) & 0xFFFFFF` and skip all the shifting (for copying the RGB all at once). It's also curious that you use the B(lue) channel from the `alpha` image, but I think it is consistent with the Python code. 